# Dialogflow - Heroku JS Integration

Tags: javascript, heroku, ecmascript-6, dialogflow-es

For starters, I have done hours of research into how to get DialogFlow to have requests fulfilled by a webhook hosted by something like Heroku. I have Heroku and nodeJS fully installed on my computer, went through the entire heroku tutorial of how to get started and everything worked fine. I don't think my problem is not having the right things installed.

I have uploaded what I have so far: https://github.com/joshua-yan/dialoguetest

This is how I started:

```
 C:\Users\******>cd C:\Users\*****\guided

 C:\Users\******\guided>npm init

 C:\Users\******\guided>npm install express body-parser
```

After that, I just created the file index.js and edited example code (provided by a guide online on an imdb api). I did the best I could with the provided code but trying **node index.js** in command prompt is insisting that my code has syntax errors that I don't think exist.

Here is `index.js`:

```
server.post('/get-movie-details', (req, res) => {

    var p1x = req.body.queryResult.parameters['p1x'];
    var p1y = req.body.queryResult.parameters['p1y'];
    var p1z = req.body.queryResult.parameters['p1z'];
    var p2x = req.body.queryResult.parameters['p2x'];
    var p2y = req.body.queryResult.parameters['p2y'];
    var p2z = req.body.queryResult.parameters['p2z'];
    var p1 = [p1x, p1y, p1z];
    var p2 = [p2x, p2y, p2z];
    var answ = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2[0] - p1[0], 2) + Math.pow(p2[1] - p1[1], 2) + Math.pow(p2[2] - p1[2], 2));
    return res.json({
        speech: answ.toString(),
        displayText: answ.toString()
    });
    (error) => {
        return res.json({
            speech: 'Something went wrong!',
            displayText: 'Something went wrong!',
            source: 'get-movie-details'
        });
    });
};

server.listen((process.env.PORT || 8000), () => {
    console.log("Server is up and running...");
});
```

If you want the error:

```
 C:\Users\******\guided\index.js:23
 });
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
```

**TLDR: I think I have no clue what I'm doing with DialogFlow and Heroku. I have DialogFlow all set up but I'm struggling very much with the fulfillment side of things.**

**My goal is simply to take integer input from DialogFlow, do some math with javascript, and return the answer. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this sort of thing? I don't care about API integration (which every guide on the internet seems to be obsessed with), I just want to do math with the parameters from DialogFlow.**

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. In the future, please include the relevant code _here_. We shouldn't have to go to GitHub just to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your code with some cruft removed, focusing on braces and parentheses:

```
server.post('/get-movie-details', (req, res) => {  // <-- Open brace...
    return res.json({
    });
    (error) => {  // <-- Where should this error function be?
                  //     It's currently inside your success function
        return res.json({
        });
    });  // <-- ...mismatched closing brace
};
```

It's more likely that you want to close your `(req, res)` function after you return `res.json()` and then open the error function as another argument to `server.post()`, e.g.

```
server.post('/get-movie-details', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({
    });
},
(error) => {
    return res.json({
    });
});
```